# How to solve Null Pointer Exception for below Selenium WebDriver POM Project

Tags: selenium-webdriver

TestBase.java

```java
public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;


    public TestBase() {

    public static void intialization() {
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("FireFox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }

}
```

LoginPage.java

```java
public class LoginPage extends TestBase{

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='email']")
    WebElement emailField;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='password']")
    WebElement passwordField;

    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='ui fluid large blue submit button']")
    WebElement loginBtn;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Forgot')]")
    WebElement forgotPass;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Classic CRM')]")
    WebElement classicCRM;

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Sign')]")
    WebElement signUp;

    public String getLoginPageTitle() {
        return driver.getTitle();
    }

    public boolean loginButtonEnabled() {
        return loginBtn.isEnabled();
    }

    public ForgotPassPage forgotPassEnabled() {
        forgotPass.click();
        return new ForgotPassPage();
    }

    public boolean classicCRMEnabled() {
        return classicCRM.isDisplayed();
    }

    public ClassicCRMPage classicCRMRedirect() {
        classicCRM.click();
        return new ClassicCRMPage();
    }

    public boolean signUpEnabled() {
        return signUp.isDisplayed();
    }

    public HomePage login(String user, String pass) {
        emailField.sendKeys(user);
        passwordField.sendKeys(pass);
        loginBtn.click();
        return new HomePage();
    }

}
```

LoginPageTest.java

```java
public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase {
    LoginPage loginPage;
    FrontPage frontPage;
    ForgotPassPage forgetPassPage;
    ClassicCRMPage classicrmPage;

    public LoginPageTest() {
        super();
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        intialization();
        frontPage = new FrontPage();
        frontPage.loginRedirect();
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void testLoginPageTitle() {
        String title = loginPage.getLoginPageTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Cogmento CRM");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void testLoginButtonEnable() {
        boolean btn = loginPage.loginButtonEnabled();
        Assert.assertTrue(btn);
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void testClassicCRMDisplay() {
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.classicCRMEnabled());
    }

    @Test(priority=4)
    public void testClassicCRMRedirect() {
        classicrmPage = loginPage.classicCRMRedirect();
    }

    @Test(priority=5)
    public void testForgetPassword() {
        forgetPassPage = loginPage.forgotPassEnabled();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

When I try to run Test File using TestNG I am getting below error message:
java.lang.NullPointerException

> com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPage.loginButtonEnabled(LoginPage.java:39)
>   com.crm.qa.tests.LoginPageTest.testLoginButtonEnable(LoginPageTest.java:39)

I am learning Selenium WebDriver and this is for my personal experience. Not related to any working Project

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, I haven't initialized my Page Object Elements. After Initializing it worked as Charm

Comment: Could you add the line of code that fixed it? Maybe it will help others in the future when reading your question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below constructor in your LoginPage.java

```
public LoginPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

This will initialize the Page Factory Elements.